# Jquery make columns same height as tallest

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/gdqcLbqt/

I have bootstrap columns with different amounts of content and so different heights.

I need the columns to be the same heights.

I need to find the tallest column and then make all the columns that height.

Sorry I don;t know where to start with this so I have no code to start.

```
        .block{
            background: red; 
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .col-sm-4{
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply go though each of them, find the tallest, then assign that found tallest value to all the `.block`'s:

```
var tallest = 0;
$(".block").each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > tallest)
        tallest = $(this).height();
});
$(".block").height(tallest);
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gdqcLbqt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

create a local variable and save the maximum height into it

```
   var highestCol = Math.max($('#element1').height(), $('#element2').height());

   $('.elements').height(highestCol);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the maximum height from all the value then apply to all the blocks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tempHeightArr = []; 
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".row").find(".col-sm-4").each(function(){
     tempHeightArr.push($(this).find(".block").height());
});
 maxHeight =  Math.max.apply(Math,tempHeightArr);
 $(".block").css("height",maxHeight);
});
```

### Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/13tnu07c/1/).